# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while handling upload

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I need to upload an image to datastore. Image being received using from servlet.

Exception occurs in **UploadServlet.java** at:

```
String pid =
                        ImageDAO.getInstance().insertImage(image);
```

**UploadServlet.java:**

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob;
import dao.ImageDAO;
import model.Image;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemIterator;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemStream;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.io.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Date;

public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
        FileItemIterator iterator = null;
        try {
            iterator = upload.getItemIterator(req);
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
                InputStream stream = item.openStream();
                if (item.isFormField()) {
                    // Handle form field
                    Blob bImg = new
                            Blob(IOUtils.toByteArray(stream));
                    Image image = new Image(bImg);

                    String fileName = item.getName();
                    if (fileName != null) {
                        fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(fileName);
                    }
                    image.setName(fileName);
                    image.setDate(new Date());

                    String pid =
                            ImageDAO.getInstance().insertImage(image);

                } else {
                    // Handle the uploaded file
                }
            }

            resp.sendRedirect("image");
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

where the code in **ImageDAO.java** is:

```
public String insertImage(Image image) {
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        try {
            pm.makePersistent(image);
        } finally {
            pm.close();
        }
        return image.getId().toString();
    }
```

**Error:**

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection.close(DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:146)
    at org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl.closeAllConnections(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:181)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager$1.preClose(AbstractStoreManager.java:260)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.close(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1112)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.internalClose(JDOPersistenceManager.java:359)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.releasePersistenceManager(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:1106)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.close(JDOPersistenceManager.java:343)
    at dao.ImageDAO.insertImage(ImageDAO.java:25)
    at UploadServlet.doPost(UploadServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:490)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

---

**UPDATE:**
The problem dissapeared when the project was deployed on Google App Engine server. I need to fix this problem to be able to debug app on local machine.

Comment: You are in the finally block w/out catching any exceptions.   Are you certain something hasn't gone south in makePersistant that might effect this case.

Comment: I have no idea. But IDE points the error in this line `pm.close();`

Comment: add a catch(Exception e) { log soemthing about e } finally {pm.close}